# Opening file when hyperlink is clicked - Java FX

Tags: java

I have hyperlink created in a textflow container in Java FX. The code provided below only opens the last hyperlinked file even when the preceding links are clicked. I think the problem is in the iteration. Kindly bear with me as I am still fresh on Java. `

```
String[] splits = lessonResources.split("\\s+");

       for(String s: splits){
             link = new Hyperlink(s);
             lessonResourcesTextFlow.getChildren().add(link);
             linked = new File(s);   
             link.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {   
                  try {
                         if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
                               try {
                                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(linked);
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                       Logger.getLogger(LessonPlanController.class.getName   ()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            }
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println(e);
                   }
               }); 
         }
```

Comment: Next time you ask random strangers to donate their free time to solving your problem for free, at least take the time to use your spacebar correctly and format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the file constructor within the link event handler solved my problem.

```
String[] splits = lessonResources.split("\\s+");
    for(String s: splits){
            link = new Hyperlink(s);
            lessonResourcesTextFlow.getChildren().add(link);


            link.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {  
                    linked = new File(s); 
                            try {
                                if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
                                    try {
                                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(linked);
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(LessonPlanController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }
            }); 

    }
```